# Django - ManyToMany through synthetic relation fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have such models in my application:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass


class MyObject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=False, db_index=True)

    related_users = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, through='RelatedUsers', related_name='related_users'
    )


class RelatedUsers(models.Model):
    my_object = models.ForeignKey(
        MyObject, related_name='my_object_related_users'
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    type = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        choices=RelatedUsersTypes.choices()
    )

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'my_object', 'type')


class FunctionalityRelatedUsersTypes(BaseChoiceEnum):
    TYPE_1 = 'TYPE 1'
    TYPE_2 = 'TYPE 2'
    TYPE_3 = 'TYPE 3'
    TYPE_4 = 'TYPE 4'
    TYPE_5 = 'TYPE 5'
```

I'm wondering if there is an option to create some kind of synthetic relations on `MyObject`.
I would like to be able to get users by type using one field, example: `related_users_type_1`. I'd like to use it in DRF serializer as well (so I can pass just List of ids, and relation will create a Proxy object with the corresponding type).

Pseudocode:

```
related_users_type_1 = models.RelationField(RelatedUsers, filter={'type': 'TYPE_1'})
```

Sample payload I want to send:

```
{
    "related_users_type_1": [1, 2, 3],
    "related_users_type_2": [3]
}
```

Expected result:

- 3 `RelatedUsers` with `TYPE_1`
- 1 `RelatedUser` with `TYPE_2`

Comment: Name your classes with singular nouns! `RelatedUser` instead of `RelatedUsers`, and so on. This is a best-practice naming convention. When you instantiate an object of the class you're creating a new `RelatedUser`, just a single one, not many of them.

Comment: Are you just looking to create a structure to label relationships between users and be able to use that relationship as a filter? I;m having a little bit of trouble understanding...

Comment: Main purpose is simplifying API request/responses, so user does not have to pass list of structures with `user_id` and `type` to `related_users` field in payload. He passes just list of ids to `related_users_type_1`, and he can update only users with `TYPE_1` via patch (doesn't have to send whole list of already existing users of other types)

Comment: working on an answer... it's pretty simple to the point where I still feel like I don't understand the whole picture...

Comment: Updated my answer, hopefully this helps you out :)

Answer (score 0):

From the comments we've had, I think your problem can be solved with models as such:

```
# just for completeness. should probably use an actual user model
class User (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class MyObject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    users = models.ManyToMany(User, through='MyObjectUsers', symmetrical=False)

    def add_relations(self, relations):
        for key, list in relations.items():
            for id in list:
                users.add(user=User.objects.get(pk=id), rel_type=key)



class MyObjectUsers(models.Model):
    REL_TYPE_CHOICES=(
        ('TYPE1','TYPE1'),
        ('TYPE2','TYPE2')
    )
    myobject = models.ForeignKey('MyObject', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    rel_type = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices = REL_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

The [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#s-extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) shows you how to traverse the relationship.

With the above implementation of `MyObject`, you should be able to to call `.add_relations({'TYPE1':[1,2,3]})` on a `MyObject` instance to create the relationships you need.

I wrote this on my phone so I don't really know if it runs (will test tomorrow)

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but I know how to create such through relationship. For example in SQLAlchemy I can create multiple relationship through same table using primaryjoin. So it would look like: `related_users_type_1 = db.relationship('RelatedUsers', primaryjoin='RelatedUsers.type==TYPE_1')`

Comment: I see what you mean. I think what you are looking for is doable with [model managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/) and/or [model methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#model-methods) or some involved logic in the view to implement custom methods such as the ones you are looking for. Will edit the answer to reflect that tomorrow. For now, I need sleep! :P @Blewji